# function called twice with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using a DuplexChannelFactory to connect my client to my server and what I want to do now is connect the server to each client that will register on the server. But every time I launch a client, my "init()" function is ran twice. And my DuplexChannelFactory on the server side doesn't work.

Here is how I open my server for clients :

```
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(NewServeur.NewServeur));
host.Open();
```

with its App.Config :

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MEX">
                <serviceMetadata />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="MEX" name="NewServeur.NewServeur">
            <endpoint address="IProxyNewServeur" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="configWin" name="NetTcpEndpoint" contract="ProxyNewServeur.IProxyNewServeur" />
            <endpoint address="MEX" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                name="MexTcpEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://192.156.142.176:8080/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="configWin">
        <security mode="None"></security>
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Here is how I connect my client to my server :

```
void init()
{
   ServiceCablingCallback ServiceCablingCallback = new ServiceCablingCallback();
   ServiceCablingCallback.ClientNotified += ServiceCablingCallback_ClientNotified;
   this._instanceContext = new InstanceContext(ServiceCablingCallback);
   this.factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<ProxyNewServeur.IProxyNewServeur>(_instanceContext, "configClient");
   this._serviceCablingClient = factory.CreateChannel();
   this._clientId = _serviceCablingClient.Subscribe();
}
```

with its App.Config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://192.156.142.176:8080/IProxyNewServeur"
    binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="configWin" contract="ALSTEF.Cabling.ProxyNewServeur.IProxyNewServeur"
    name="configClient" />
</client>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="configWin">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

This works fine, but now I want to do the reverse thing, meaning connecting the server to the client. In order to do so, I added those lines before the last line of my client :

```
 host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(_serviceCablingClient.getIp()));
 host.Open();
```

with getIp() returning the Ip address + the port 4242 of my client.

and this to the client App.config

```
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MEX">
      <serviceMetadata />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MEX" name="Client.Model.Service">
    <endpoint address="IClientFunction" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ClientConfig"
      name="NetTcpEndpoint" contract="ProxyNewServeur.IClientFunction" />
    <endpoint address="MEX" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="MexTcpEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<!-- in the bindings html tag -->
 <binding name="ClientConfig">
   <security mode="None" />
 </binding>
```

And I modified the _serviceCablingClient.Subscribe() by adding those lines (so in the server)

```
public Guid Subscribe()
{
   ProxyNewServeur.INewServeurCallback callback =
            OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ProxyNewServeur.INewServeurCallback>();

   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpointProperty = 
            OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;


   Guid clientId = Guid.NewGuid();
   if (callback != null)
   {
      lock (clientsCallback)
      {
         clientsCallback.Add(clientId, callback);
      }
   }

   /* code I added */
   string addr = "net.tcp://" + endpointProperty.Address + ":" + "4242" + "/IClientFunction";

   ClientCallback cb = new ClientCallback();
   var Okvp = new KeyValuePair<Guid, DuplexChannelFactory<ProxyNewServeur.IClientFunction>>(clientId,
   new DuplexChannelFactory<ProxyNewServeur.IClientFunction>(new InstanceContext(cb), "configServer",
   new EndpointAddress(addr)));
   this.DictClient.Add(Okvp, Okvp.Value.CreateChannel());
   this.DictClient[Okvp].CreateCallbackChannel();
   /* end code I added */
}
```

And I added this to the server App.config

```
<client>
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ClientConfig" contract="ProxyNewServeur.IClientFunction" name="configServer" />
</client>  

<!-- in the bindings html tag -->
<binding name="ClientConfig">
  <security mode="None" />
</binding>
```

Here is how I define my ProxyServeur file

```
namespace ProxyNewServeur
{
    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(INewServeurCallback))]
    public interface IProxyNewServeur
    {
       [OperationContract]
       Guid Subscribe();
       [OperationContract]
       string getIp();
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface INewServeurCallback
    {
       [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
       void HandleMessage(Message message);
    }

    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IClientCallback))]
    public interface IClientFunction
    {
       [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
       void CreateCallbackChannel();
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IClientCallback
    {
       [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
       void BroadcastToServer(bool isActive, Guid ClientId);
    }
}
```

Now When I launch a client the line

```
DictClient[Okvp].CreateCallbackChannel();
```

won't work and I will go twice in the

```
init()
{ /* code*/
}
```

function.

I have no idea why this is happening. I did the exact same thing in a test project and it worked fine.

**EDIT**

As it turns out, you cannot have a DuplexChannelFactory<> and a ServiceHost in the same method. So what I did is that I added a new Class "DoubleConnection" that have only one attribute.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class DoubleConnection : ProxyNewServeur.IClientFunction
{
    public ServiceHost host;

    public void CreateCallbackChannel()
    {}
    public void isActive()
    {}
}
```

and in the init() function I removed

```
 host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(_serviceCablingClient.getIp()));
 host.Open();
```

and added

```
 varClass = new DoubleConnection();
 varClass.host = new ServiceHost(typeof(DoubleConnection), new Uri(_serviceCablingClient.getIp()));
 varClass.host.Open();
```

I works fine now but I still don't know why you cannot have a DuplexChannelFactory<> and a ServiceHost in the same method.

Comment: That's not how a Duplex channel works.  You don't create a ServiceHost on both the client and the server.  The DuplexChannel provides both directions of communication, so there is no point to creating a new channel the other way.

Comment: I do feel superdumb now